# glsl float cast to int

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

Fragment shader code :

```
varying vec2 v_texCoord;  // no use 
uniform sampler2D uInputTex; // no use 
highp float xxx = 3025.0;
void main() {
    int ixxx = int(xxx);
    if (ixxx == 3024) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);
    }
    else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
    }
}
```

If I use `highp` to declare `ixxx` , I get the right result .
if I just use default precision , just `int ixxx = int(xxx);` I compare `ixxx` with `3024` is correct ， and I compare  `ixxx` with `3025` is correct too . why ?

Comment: Seems like the default precision uses half float. So due to lack of half float precision (3 decimal digits approx.) your half( 3025.0 ) is rounded to the same value as half( 3024 )

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to floating point storage differences. The GLSL spec (section 4.5) only states requirements about the precision of floats, but encourages the use of an IEEE format. Assuming this is the way your driver is storing the numbers, in IEEE format many values cannot be exactly represented, because the storage is a fixed number of bits (eg. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format for an in-depth description of IEEE 754 32-bit float).

Your literal will instead be the closest value that can be represented. This might be slightly above the actual value. Since you are (potentially, and likely) changing the number of bits in the storage, it may be that representation in one number of bits is above (eg. with highp), and another is below the literal value (eg. with mediump). When constructing the int from the float, truncation occurs - so if the literal representation is below 3025.0 (eg. 3024.9999..), it becomes 3024.

There are several possible solutions to this, probably the easiest is just use an int directly. You could also 'bump' the literal number, to ensure that it won't get truncated (eg. make it 3025.1, which in any reasonable representation will get truncated to 3025).